# Are these step-rounds equivalents?

Tags: c++, rounding

[This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a430d8f3303f3a6) is the code I've:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef std::numeric_limits< double > dbl;

double StepValue(double value) {
    return floor(0.5 + value / 0.1) * 0.1;
}

void PrintValue(int maxlen, const char *fmt, ...) 
{
    char buffer[20];
    va_list arglist;
    va_start(arglist, fmt);
    vsnprintf(buffer, maxlen, fmt, arglist);
    va_end(arglist);

    std::cout << "p: " << buffer << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout.precision(dbl::max_digits10);
    std::cout << std::fixed;

    double inputValue = 13.55121341223423457;
    std::cout << "v: " << inputValue << std::endl;

    double steppedValue = StepValue(inputValue);
    std::cout << "f: " << steppedValue << std::endl;   

    PrintValue(20, "%.1f", inputValue);
}
```

Basically, I take an `inputValue` and I round it to the nearest stepped value I need (which is 1 digit after the comma), using the nearest double that can represent it (the one I assign to `steppedValue`).

So for example, taking the `inputValue = 13.55121341223423457` and using a step of `0.1`, the value is `13.6` (which is actually `13.60000000000000142` due to the floating point math; but that's not the point, the point is it return .6 conceptually).

Later, I take the same `inputValue` and I print out using the `vsnprintf` function, considering again a step of `0.1`. Which prints correctly `13.6`.

My question is: can exist ANY `inputValue` that round to different stepped value between using my step function or `vsnprintf`? i.e. can the two result from my step function and `vsnprintf` be inconsistent such as calculating/printing value at different step?

Comment: Please edit your post with the *text* of the code.  Firewalls block links to code pages, which means fewer people can help you.  No screen snapshots please.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: done ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not equivalent.  Because you're dividing by 0.1 (which cannot be represented exactly), rather than multiplying by 10 (which can), there is a number very close to the midpoint where the rounding would go in different directions.  This can depend on the compiler and execution environment.  With Visual Studio 2015, compiling as a 32 bit program, using

```
double inputValue = std::nextafter(0.05, 0.0);
```

gives a values of

```
f: 0.10000000000000001
p: 0.0
```

Multiplying by 10 in your rounding may fix the problem, but that depends on how `vsnprintf` handles rounding.

Changing `StepValue` to `return std::round(value * 10.0) / 10.0;` will resolve the problem with the example value I've provided.

Comment: Uhm interessant! So how can I "sync" the two operations? I don't know how `vsnprintf` handles its rounding. Of course it won't do mine "floor + 0.5" approch.

Comment: It can use "round" as well, but which tie-breaking? It seems a guess...

Comment: Using `round` is probably the best guess to use, unless you want to delve into your C library's implementation of the `printf` family to see exactly.  The problem only happens with values that are very close to the rounding edge value.

Comment: Yes, but I can't discard those values, even if tiny! What if the printf family use a different kind of round? Again, there would be trouble. A step of difference is a lot...

Comment: @markzzz The `printf` rounding will be done according to language rules (round-to-nearest), and `round` should be doing the same sort of rounding.

Comment: But there are lots of round-to-nearest options: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Comparison_of_rounding_modes . What if `round` use Round half down and `printf` Round half to even? +1.5 will display differently...

Comment: @markzzz Rounding is handled in an implementation defined manor, but I'd be surprised if the `round` function did it differently than `printf`.

Comment: Who know? Maybe it set/get a different way prior http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfenv/fesetround/ . I think we can just "trust" its the same... as well for floating point math and printf